# MPI design in loop code

Tags: fortran, mpi

My sample fortran codes are like this:

```
call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ntasks, ierr)

if (myid==0) then
10  serial_subroutine1   
end if

parallel_function (myid, ntasks)

if (myid==0) then
   serial_subroutine2
   if (some requirements meet) go to 10
end if

call MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)
end
```

It seems like some of outputs in the serial_subroutine1 is later than the outputs in parallel_function. And the program won't output any in the serial_subroutine2 just like it has stopped.

I was wondering what caused this problem and how to solve this problem? How should I design this kind of codes by MPI?

Your answer will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you perhaps make the example valid Fortran?  I can possibly infer what you mean by `10  serial_subroutine1`, but `go to 10` later on (jumping _into_ an if construct?)...

Comment: I know that jumping into an if construct is not valid. If I want to achieve this sample codes in MPI, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a loop like the following. I'm assuming you want to go through the parallel call so long as your condition is met.

```
logical :: keep_going
...

keep_going=.true.
do

  if(myid==0) call serial1()

  call parallel(myid,tasks)

! Do more serial work and test on root pe
  if(myid==0) then
    call serial2()
    keep_going=some_test_on_root_pe()
  endif

  ! let everyone know if we are continuing
  call mpi_bcast(keep_going,1,mpi_logical,0,mpi_comm_world,ierr)

  ! Do we bail out?
  if(.not. keep_going) exit
enddo
```